# Verify my proof: $B \cup(\bigcup \mathcal F) = \bigcup(\mathcal F \cup \{B\})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm self learning from the book "How to Prove it" by Velleman (3rd edition). I don't have access to a math professor, so I need a little help from the community. Please verify my proof.

Problem 17a, pag. 151

> Suppose $\mathcal F$ is a nonempty family of sets and $B$ is a set. Prove that $B \cup(\bigcup \mathcal F) = \bigcup(\mathcal F \cup \{B\})$.

**Proof**. Suppose $x \in B \cup (\bigcup \mathcal F)$, then $x \in B$ or $x \in \bigcup \mathcal F$. So there are two cases:

Case 1. $x \in B$, because $B \in (\mathcal F \cup \{B\})$, then definitely $x \in \bigcup(\mathcal F \cup \{B\})$

Case 2. $x \in \bigcup \mathcal F$, then $\exists A \in \mathcal F$ and $x \in A$. Because $A \in (\mathcal F \cup \{B\} )$, then definitely $x \in \bigcup(\mathcal F \cup \{B\})$

Now suppose $x \in \bigcup(\mathcal F \cup \{B\})$, then $\exists C \in \mathcal F$, such that $x \in C$ or $x \in B$. So there are two cases:

Case 1. $\exists C \in \mathcal F$, such that $x \in C$, then $x \in \bigcup F$, then $x \in B \cup (\bigcup \mathcal F)$.

Case 2. $x \in B$, then $x \in B \cup (\bigcup \mathcal F)$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: Note that $x\in B$ doesn't mean that $x\in\{B\}$; $\{B\}$ is a singleton with the singular element the set $B$. In fact, I don't think the claim is true; rather, it should be that $B\cup(\bigcup \mathcal{F})=\bigcup(\mathcal{F}\cup B)$ (notice the brackets).

Comment: Your proof is correct.  PCeltide's proposed change in the problem is incorrect.